# Spotfire: How to add multiple columns for line chart without using aggregation?

Tags: spotfire

I have a requirement where I need to have multiple columns to be added to Y axis in one of my Spotfire chart and I am aware of using below formula to get the required column list from "INSERT PROPERTY CONTROL OPTION", `$esc(${YAxisColumn})`
.This works fine for single column value, however I need something like below code: `$esc(${YAxisColumn}),$esc(${Y1AxisColumn}),$esc(${Y2AxisColumn})`. However this wont work saying "multiple non-aggregated expressions cannot be used on a continuous axis".

But i dont want values in Aggregated, it should be simple values as it is.However it works fine if I use something like below, using some aggregation , which i dont want.

`Sum($esc(${YAxisColumn})),Sum($esc(${Y2AxisColumn}))`

So is there any solutions for this?Below is the required solution type[image]

Edit: Adding Expression screenshot
[image]

Comment: I've tried your setting and could implement it without any issue. Does it work for you if you don't refer to properties, just type column names in the custom expression? Please also post a screenshot of the custom expression editor with the desired expression.

Comment: Those columns are SQL table columns and of data type NUMERIC.I have added the screenshot of the custom expression in the Qs.Also even if i use just column names in the custom expression i get the same error.